# How to split a List with different chunk sizes efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have the following extension method to split a `List<T>` into a list of `List<T>`'s with different chunk sizes, but I'm doubting its efficiency. Anything I can do to improve it or is it fine as is?

```
public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this List<T> source, params int[] chunkSizes)
{
    int totalSize = chunkSizes.Sum();
    int sourceCount = source.Count();
    if (totalSize > sourceCount)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Sum of chunk sizes is larger than the number of elements in source.", "chunkSizes");
    }

    List<List<T>> listOfLists = new List<List<T>>(chunkSizes.Length);
    int index = 0;
    foreach (int chunkSize in chunkSizes)
    {
        listOfLists.Add(source.GetRange(index, chunkSize));
        index += chunkSize;
    }

    // Get the entire last part if the total size of all the chunks is less than the actual size of the source
    if (totalSize < sourceCount)
    {
        listOfLists.Add(source.GetRange(index, sourceCount - totalSize));
    }

    return listOfLists;
}
```

Example code usage:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,43,23,453,34,23,112,4,23 };
var result =  list.Split(2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This gets a desired result and a has a final list part with 4 numbers as the total chunk size is 4 less than the size of my list.

I'm especially doubtful of the `GetRange` part as I fear this is just enumerating the same source over and over...

**EDIT:** I think I know a way to enumerate the source once: Just do a foreach on the source itself and keep checking if the number of iterated elements is the same as the current chunksize. If so, add the new list and go to the next chunksize. Thoughts?

Comment: Since your input's a list not an `IEnumerable`, you don't need to _worry_ about enumerating it repeatedly. `Count()` just ends up checking `Length`, and `GetRange` uses `Array.Copy behind the scenes. You don't enumerate it at all!

Comment: Its better to use 'yield return' and return IEnumerable<List<T>> instead. This will allow the chunks to be be created when the calling code requires them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance problem with this code. [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) is documented to be O(chunkSize), and this is also easy to deduce since one of the most important properties of `List<T>` is exactly that it allows O(1) indexing.

That said, you could write a more LINQ-y version of the code like this:

```
var rangeStart = 0;
var ranges = chunkSizes.Select(n => Tuple.Create((rangeStart += n) - n, n))
                       .ToArray();
var lists = ranges.Select(r => source.GetRange(r.Item1, r.Item2)).ToList();

if (rangeStart < source.Count) {
    lists.Last().AddRange(source.Skip(rangeStart));
}

return lists;
```

Comment: Okay, so because each individual chunk size is a part of n (Sum(chunks) <= n), this method is also O(n) where n is the number of elements in the source.

Comment: @Davio: Yes. I just added a more LINQ-y version of the method you might want to check out.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep my more verbose method for the time being so other colleagues can easier see what is going on. May convert it in time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this extension method to chunk the source list to the sub-lists by specified chunk size:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper methods for the lists.
/// </summary>
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<List<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this List<T> source, int chunkSize) 
    {
        return source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```